# Prevent DataGrid Groups collapsing on sort?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF data grid in which I am grouping data by a certain property.
All standard stuff.
However, when I click on one of the column headers to sort by that column, it collapses all the groups. I would like to prevent this if possible.
I can trap the DataGrid's Sorting event, and if I try to set the Expander for the group to "IsExpanded" it has no effect as it seems that IsExpanded is already true, even though it is not shown expanded.

It appears to be standard behaviour and not just with my data so any example anybody can give as to how to accomplish this would be great.

the xaml I have got for the data grid is as such:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander>
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock.Text>
                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1} Items)">
                                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                                <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                                <Binding Path="ItemCount"/>
                                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem, and it gave me a lot of headache. Finally, I've come to this, probably not the most elegant, but working solution (i had to make it work with multi-grouping too, so you'll get that functionality gratis :). 
Main idea is to remember state of each expander before sorting occur, and restore it after sorting is finished. In order to achieve this I've:

1. On every manual expanding or collapsing recorded its state (actually I keep just states of expanded expanders). As expander identifier I'm using generated id from element binded to expander)
2. On evaluating expanders' IsExpanded property used converter which checks if current expander state is in the list of saved states, and returns IsExpanded value accordingly.

Expander in GroupStyle:

```
    <Expander x:Name="exp" Expanded="exp_Expanded" Collapsed="exp_Collapsed" >
        <Expander.IsExpanded>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=expanderStateConverter}" Mode="OneWay" >
                <Binding Mode="OneWay"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="ExpandersStates" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Expander.IsExpanded>
    <!-- ... the rest of the boring expander code -->
    </Expander>
```

Replace the AncestorType Window part with your type of control if neccessary...

Code in View:

```
    public List<string> ExpandersStates {get; set; }
    private void exp_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExpandCollapseExpander(sender as Expander, e, true);
    }

    private void exp_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExpandCollapseExpander(sender as Expander, e, false);
    }

    private void ExpandCollapseExpander(Expander exp, RoutedEventArgs e, bool doExpand)
    {
        CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup = exp.DataContext as CollectionViewGroup;
        if (collectionViewGroup == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string viewGroupId = FormViewGroupIdentifier(collectionViewGroup, null);
        if (doExpand)
        {
            if (!ExpandersStates.Contains(viewGroupId))
            {
                ExpandersStates.Add(viewGroupId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ExpandersStates.Remove(viewGroupId);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public static string FormViewGroupIdentifier(CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup, string sufix)
    {
        string formViewGroupIdentifier = collectionViewGroup.Name + sufix;
        CollectionViewGroup parentgroup = GetParent(collectionViewGroup);
        if (parentgroup == null)
        {
            return formViewGroupIdentifier;
        }
        else
        {
            return FormViewGroupIdentifier(parentgroup, "putHereSomeDelimiterWhichWillNeverOccurInYourGroupingProperty" + formViewGroupIdentifier);
        }
    }

    private static CollectionViewGroup GetParent(CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup)
    {
        Type type = collectionViewGroup.GetType();
        if (type.Name == "CollectionViewGroupRoot")
        {//if we are at the root level return null as there is no parent
            return null;
        }

        CollectionViewGroup parentgroup
            = type.GetProperty("Parent", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .GetValue(collectionViewGroup, null) as CollectionViewGroup;
        return parentgroup;
    }
```

Converter:

```
public class ExpanderStateConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CollectionViewGroup collectionViewGroup = values[0] as CollectionViewGroup;
        List<string> expandersStates = values[1] as List<string>;
        if (!expandersStates.Any())
        {//prevent forming group identifier to speed up process as there are no expanded expanders anyway
            return false;
        }

        string groupId = MainWindow.FormViewGroupIdentifier(collectionViewGroup, null);
        bool contains = expandersStates.Contains(groupId);
        return contains;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[2];
    }
}
```

I'm aware that generating identifiers for expanders by using arbitrary delimiter here is not the best practice, and I'm open for suggestions on how to improve this.

Full code available here: [ExpandersForSO2](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5382FFFF70512D0E&id=5382FFFF70512D0E!127)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply change the  `<Expander>` node by adding: `<Expander IsExpanded="True">`?